# Get unique rows of dask array without using dask dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dask

**Is there a way of getting unique rows of a dask array  that is larger than the available memory? Ideally, without converting it to a dask DataFrame?**

I currently use this approach

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd

dx = da.random.random((10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
ddf = dd.from_dask_array(dx)
ddf = ddf.drop_duplicates()
dx = ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
```

which works for bigger data-sets than `np.unique(dx, axis=0)` but eventually also runs out of memory.

I'm using Python 3.6 (but can upgrade), Dask 0.20 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always just use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy-unique):

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

dx = da.random.random((10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
dx = np.unique(dx, axis=0)
```

This may still leave you with memory issues when you try to use it with "data sets larger than my RAM", since it will run the calculation on a single node. There is a `dask.array.unique` function, but it doesn't support the `axis` keyword yet. This means that it will flatten the array and return the unique single values, not the unique rows. The sorting functions that would allow for any kind of a hand-rolled parallelized version don't seem to be implemented in `dask.array` either.

My recommendation would be to just suck it up for now and convert to `dask.dataframe`. This approach assures that you get the correct output, even if it's not the fastest conceivable implementation.

#### Edit

I initially thought there might be a simple hack that could be used to implement the `axis` parameter for `dask.array.unique`. However, the [blob type trick that `numpy.unqiue` uses to implement its own `axis` keyword](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d1e0a43ff910e15034997b9b646b38014382fe6e/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L280) turns out to not carry over easily to Dask arrays, owing to the presence of chunks.

So no clever worakaround for now. Just use `dask.dataframe`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I get a MemoryError error